# STM32f429 HID HOST and MSC HOST How to Combine?

Tags: stm32f4discovery

I am using STM32f429 discovery. I am using USB PORT in FS MODE.
I want to use two devices: one is a pen drive and the other is a keyboard. When the pen drive is plugged in, the host works as msc_host_device and when the keyboard is plugged in, the host works as hid_host_device on the same USB port.

Using a separate library, both devices are working but now I want to combine them.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
Projects/STM32469I-Discovery/Applications/USB_Host/DynamicSwitch_Standalone
```

in STM32CubeF4, it does exactly what you are trying. As far as I understand it, the basic idea is

- calling `USBH_RegisterClass()` after `USBH_Init()` for each device class the application can handle
- when the USB callback function is called with `HOST_USER_CLASS_ACTIVE`, the device class becomes available from `USBH_GetActiveClass()`

Comment: thanks. its very useful. now how can i do the same for STM32F429 Board. How can i do this with cubeMX ?